# Как объединить диски с XEN-хостов в одно хранилище?

Tags: виртуализация, диск, xen

Есть 4 сервера с установленным XenServer 7.х. На каждом сервере есть большой диск (6Тб - raid10). Как объединить эти диски в одно хранилище для совместного использования?
То-есть нужен аналог vSAN от VMware.